# Android Ontouchlistener not showing correct id of the imageview when it's clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, ontouchlistener

I have a fragment containing 6 imageviews in its layout of my android application. When I click on the images, It should toast me the id of the imageview. But instead it is toasting as false, when I click on any of the imageviews. My images are of triangular in shape and to check whether I have clicked inside or not of the image, I have used on touch listener in my project. But it is not showing me the id of the imageview when I click on it. I'm using a navigation drawer in my project and so I'm using here fragments instead of activity. Here is my code:

HomeFragment.java (Edited)

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        final OnTouchListener changeColorListener = new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
                int color = 0;
                try {
                    color = bmp.getPixel((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT)
                    return false;
                else {
 //edited part
 if(v.getId() == R.id.loginbutton){
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
 //edited part
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }


        };
        ImageView loginbutton=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        loginbutton.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        loginbutton.setOnTouchListener(changeColorListener); 

        ImageView flightbutton=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.flightbutton);
        flightbutton.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        flightbutton.setOnTouchListener(changeColorListener); 

        ImageView registerbutton=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.hotelbutton);
        registerbutton.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        registerbutton.setOnTouchListener(changeColorListener); 

        ImageView supportbutton=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.supportbutton);
        supportbutton.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        supportbutton.setOnTouchListener(changeColorListener);                   

        ImageView aboutusbutton=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutusbutton);
        aboutusbutton.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        aboutusbutton.setOnTouchListener(changeColorListener);                   

        ImageView contactbutton=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.contactbutton);
        contactbutton.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        contactbutton.setOnTouchListener(changeColorListener);                   

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/supportbutton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:background="@drawable/support" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flightbutton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/supportbutton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/supportbutton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flight3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hotelbutton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/flightbutton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/flightbutton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/hotel2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aboutusbutton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelbutton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flightbutton"
        android:background="@drawable/aboutus" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/hotelbutton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/hotelbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contactbutton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loginbutton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/contact"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Edit:
Actually my intention was to check which button was clicked actually. The problem is when I added the edited part and run the app, It's intersting that when I click on the contact image, actually the toast is showing as Login button. But I have given in the else condition with the id of the login imageview, so that when I click on the login image, it should trigger the toast. Instead on clicking the contact image, the toast for login is actually called. How is that possible? Is there any solution for it...

Comment: Have you debugged the code on the `onTouch` to see what the `color` is returning? You could also toast the color value.

Comment: That depends on the IDE you are using, but put a breakpoint on the line `if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT)` and run the app in debug mode. When you click on the image it should pause the app at that point and let you examine the `color` variable. You could also write the color value to your log (`Log.d("Your Tag", color);`), or write a `Toast` to show your color value.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Why is it needed to know what is the value of `color`? From the description I understand that a toast message is shown, which means that the `color` is not transparent.

Comment: @TeeJay Well, your color result is clearly coming back as != Color.TRANSPARENT, so a first step (in my opinion) is to find out what is actually being returned from your `color = bmp.getPixel((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());`.

Comment: @TeeJay Regarding your edit, you should put the edited part inside `case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:` and try like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [Toast.makeText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) there are two `makeText()` methods:

- public static Toast makeText (Context context, int resId, int duration)
- public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)

I assume you want to display the ID as a string, but in this case you are passing `v.getId()` which returns an int, so actually the first method is called, which looks for a resource. So in the first place you could make it
`Toast.makeText(getActivity(), v.getId() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`
  which will turn your second argument into a string.

Comment: Actually, when I click on the contact image, login is toasted. and when I click on the login image, contact is toasted...How is that happening??

Comment: @TeeJay I'm here :) Did you try my proposals here and in the comment and what is the result from it?

Comment: Actually, when I click on the contact image, login is toasted. and when I click on the login image, contact is toasted...How is that happening??

Comment: Can you try removing the Contact image and then try testing by pressing on Login to see what will be toasted?

Comment: From the code provided I don't know what is the reason for this behaviour. If you provide the complete code, I can test on my side and check what the issue is.

Comment: Actually it is not related to any issue with the code. When I cleaned the code and run my app, it works without any problem. Now the problem is solved...